# Replacing values with random values from other table. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update names in a table with random names from another table. There's real user names in the table Users. There's made up names in the table tmp_users. I'd like to update all the names in Users table with random names from the tmp_users table. The idea is to anonymize real production data with fake customers. There are fewer entries in the tmp_users table so I don't think I can correlate on an id.

The problem I have is that all users gets set to the same name.

Some sample data:

```
create table users
(
  name varchar2(50)
);

create table tmp_users
(
  name varchar2(50)
);

insert into users values ('Cora');
insert into users values ('Rayna');
insert into users values ('Heidi');
insert into users values ('Gilda');
insert into users values ('Dorothy');
insert into users values ('Elena');
insert into users values ('Providencia');
insert into users values ('Louetta');
insert into users values ('Portia');
insert into users values ('Rodrick');
insert into users values ('Rocco');
insert into users values ('Nelson');
insert into users values ('Derrick');
insert into users values ('Everett');
insert into users values ('Nisha');
insert into users values ('Amy');
insert into users values ('Hyun');
insert into users values ('Brendon');
insert into users values ('Gabriela');
insert into users values ('Melina');

insert into tmp_users values ('Snow White');
insert into tmp_users values ('Cinderella');
insert into tmp_users values ('Aurora');
insert into tmp_users values ('Ariel');
insert into tmp_users values ('Belle');
insert into tmp_users values ('Jasmine');
insert into tmp_users values ('Pocahontas');
insert into tmp_users values ('Mulan');
insert into tmp_users values ('Tinker Bell');
insert into tmp_users values ('Anna');
insert into tmp_users values ('Elsa');

--Wrong, sets all users to the same random name
update users set name = (select name from (select name from tmp_users order by sys_guid()) where rownum = 1);

--Wrong, sets all users to the same random name
update users set name = (select name from (select name from tmp_users order by dbms_random.value) where rownum = 1);
```

When doing this:

```
select * from users;
```

The result I get is something like this, which I don't want.

```
Cinderella
Cinderella
Cinderella
Cinderella
Cinderella
...
```

I'd like to assign a random name to each row in the Users table. Not the same name to all rows. I'd like somthing like this:

```
Mulan
Cinderella
Belle
Elsa
Jasmine
Tinker Bell
...
```

Any idea how this can be done? I'm using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition 11.2.0.2.0. It would be easy to do with a cursor but I'm trying to figure out how to do it with a set operation.

**Update:**

I've now tested on two different Oracle versions. The correlated subquery solution doesn't work on Oracle Database 11g Express Edition 11.2.0.2.0.
But it does work sometimes on Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition    11.2.0.4.0. On one table it works all the time and on another it never works.

Answer (score 3):

Testing with 11.2.0.4 the following works, similar to what @VR46 suggested:

```
SQL> UPDATE users u
  2     SET name = (SELECT name
  3                   FROM (SELECT NAME,
  4                                row_number() over(ORDER BY dbms_random.value) rn
  5                           FROM tmp_users) tu
  6                    WHERE u.name IS NOT NULL
  7                         AND rn = 1);
20 rows updated

SQL> select * from users;
NAME
--------------------------------------------------
Ariel
Aurora
Belle
Ariel
Anna
Mulan
Aurora
Ariel
Mulan
Tinker Bell
Mulan
Ariel
Aurora
Pocahontas
Pocahontas
Aurora
Snow White
Mulan
Aurora
Anna
20 rows selected
```

Comment: I get the wrong behaviour on my Oracle Database 11g Express Edition 11.2.0.2.0. All names in Users table get the same name. When I run the inner select by itself it works correctly but when it's used as a correlated subquery it doesn't. Perhaps it's just that this is broken in my version as @Alex Poole gives some hints about regarding MOS note 420779.1. I don't have access to Oracle support myself so I don't know what it says exactly.

Comment: I get the same results as @johanrex. All values after the update are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think correlating the sub-query will pull random names from Sub-Query

```
UPDATE users 
SET    name = (SELECT name 
               FROM   (SELECT name 
                       FROM   tmp_users tu 
                       ORDER  BY Sys_guid()) 
               WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
                 AND users.name <> name );
```

Comment: WHERE  ( users.name = 'A' 
                                 OR 1 = 1 ) ?

Comment: I don't quite follow the correlation logic but it gives this error: "SQL Error: ORA-00904: "USERS"."NAME": invalid identifier"

Comment: @user1073476 - Not sure how to do it in Oracle. But the idea is to correlate the sub-query with the update table

Comment: @user1073476 - try moving the condition to outer query

Comment: @VR46 Did you update your query? Anyway I tried it with the correlation in the outer query and it's the same behaviour.

Comment: @user1073476 - check now

Comment: Poking at this a bit, the optimiser seems to see the 1=1 early and that breaks the correlation; which doesn't quite work anyway - just `users.name != name` does though. The bigger, less obvious, problem is the ordering not working with `sys_guid()` in the subquery, which looks like a bug.

Comment: @VR46. Nope. Still the same.

Comment: I get the same results with this query as I got with @johanrex's query. All results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need some correlation, as @VR46 suggested; but sys_guid() doesn't work for this (in 11gR2 anyway; I think the optimiser is only evaluating it once in this scenario for some reason, perhaps); you can use dbms_random.value though:

```
update users u set name = (
  select name from (
    select name from tmp_users order by dbms_random.value
  )
  where rownum = 1 and u.name is not null
);

NAME                                             
--------------------------------------------------
Jasmine                                           
Tinker Bell                                       
Ariel                                             
Elsa                                              
Elsa                                              
Elsa                                              
Belle                                             
Snow White                                        
...
```

If you don't want aubquery you could use keep dense rank instead:

```
update users u set name = (
  select max(name) keep (dense_rank first order by dbms_random.value)
  from tmp_users
  where u.name is not null
);

NAME                                             
--------------------------------------------------
Mulan                                             
Anna                                              
Snow White                                        
Elsa                                              
Tinker Bell                                       
Belle                                             
Belle                                             
Elsa                                              
...
```

The correlation just has to be true; if you have null values in your user table this will update them to null, and you could use a different condition if that is an issue.

From comments it seems you have the same problem with `dbms_random` in 11.2.0.2 as I have with `sys_guid` in 11.2.0.3 and 11.2.0.4. If your users table also has a numeric unique/primary key such as an ID you can use that for the correlation and pass it into the `value` function, which *might* make a difference, but I don't have a suitable instance to test against:

```
update users u set name = (
  select max(name) keep (dense_rank first order by dbms_random.value(0, u.id))
  from tmp_users
);
```

MOS note 420779.1  includes the line "Including DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE in a subquery may or may not work depending on the optimization and execution code path chosen", which seems to be the problem here.

You could also try variations with merge, e.g. (again assuming there's an ID you can use):

```
merge into users u
using (
  select u.id, max(tu.name) keep (dense_rank first 
    order by dbms_random.value(0, u.id)) as name
  from users u
  cross join tmp_users tu
  group by u.id
) tu
on (tu.id = u.id)
when matched then update set u.name = tu.name;
```

The cross join may make this impractical though, depending on the number of rows you actually have in each table.

Comment: Did you try those examples? From what I can see both produce the same wrong result.

Comment: @user1073476 - I did. Both produced random values, in 11.2.0.4.7. Which version isn't it working on?

Comment: I'm using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition 11.2.0.2.0. When I do a "select * from users" all the users have the same name.

Comment: @user1073476 - I don't have that version to check against; works in 11.2.0.3 too, which doesn't help you.

Comment: @user1073476 - not sure it'll work still, but you could try using a unique/primary key on the real table as an argument to `value` to see if that makes the optimiser treat it differently. I can't test, sadly.

Comment: Clever trick. Though there isn't a value function that takes one parameter, right? There is one that takes no parameters and there is one that takes two (low and high). I don't see how I can fit in your suggestion in that.

Comment: @user1073476 - as long as one of the values is unique it doesn't matter about the other one (as long as the second is higher than the first). If you have a key that is a positive integer then using zero for the first argument would be OK? That's what I tried it with anyway. If you prefer you could do `(u.id -1, u.id)` or `(-abs(u.id), abs(u.id))` or something but I don't think you need to. Curious if it works at all in your version though.

Comment: The sad thing is that I don't have an ID on the Users table. The name is the primary key. One can question the sanity of that but it's how it is. I've spent some time trying to hash the name and casting that hash back into a number that could be used as the upper bound for dbms_random.value(lower, upper) but I haven't been successful in that last step. The real tables contains ~2 million and 10k rows respectively so the cross join would be best to avoid. I'll probably go with a cursor if nothing extraordinary appears out of the blue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more approach, which uses rowid and modulus:

```
MERGE into users_tab u
USING (
    select 
        actual.row_id as actual_rowid,
        actual.rnum actual_rnum, 
        actual.name actual_name, 
        fake.rnum fake_rnum, 
        fake.name fake_name, 
        mod(actual.rnum, fake_count.cnt) modulus
    from
    (
    select rownum rnum, name, rowid as row_id
    from users_tab
    ) actual,
    (
    select rownum-1 rnum, name
    from (select distinct name from tmp_users_tab)
    ) fake,
    (select count(distinct name) cnt from tmp_users_tab) fake_count
    where mod(actual.rnum, fake_count.cnt) = fake.rnum
) x
ON (x.actual_rowid = u.rowid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    set name = x.fake_name;
```

Not sure about how this will perform on a very large user table, however.  Its not random, but follows a series of fake names.  So if you have 10 fake names, records 1->10 in users will be assigned fake names 1->10, and user 11 will start over with fake name #1.

The USING query has extra fields for testing.